# Using SQL for cleaning up JIRA database

Tags: sql, jira

Has anyone had luck with removing large amount of issues from a jira database instead of using the frontend? Deleting 60000 issues with the bulktools is not really feasible.

Last time I tried it, the jira went nuts because of its own way of doing indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We got gutsy and did a truncate on the jiraissues table and then use the rebuild index feature on the frontend. It looks like it's working!

Answer (score 3):

How about doing a backup to xml, editing the xml, and reimporting?

Comment: I have had success with this method, but never had the guts to try SQL on their schema.

Comment: The backup takes quite a while too, but this might be a usable idea

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but I see that this question was just edited recently, so to chime in:

Writing directly to the JIRA database is problematic. The reindex feature suggested in the Oct 14 08 answer just rebuilds the Lucene index, so it is unlikely to clean up everything that needs to be cleaned up from the database on a modern JIRA instance. Off the top of my head, this will probably leave data lying around in the following tables, among others:

- custom field data (customfieldvalue table)
- issue links (issuelink table)
- versions and components (nodeassociation table, which contains other stuff too, so be careful!)
- remote issue links or wiki mentions (remotelink table)

If one has already done such a manual delete on production, it's always a good idea to run the database integrity checker (YOURJIRAURL/secure/admin/IntegrityChecker!default.jspa) to make sure that nothing got seriously broken.

Fast forwarding to 2014, the best solution is to write a quick shell script that uses the [REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/6.2.4/#d2e3848) to delete all of the required issues. (The [JIRA CLI](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/JIRA+Command+Line+Interface) plugin is usually a good option for automating certain types of tasks too, but as far as I can tell, it does not currently support the deletion of issues, so the REST API is your best bet.)

Comment: For deleting more than a few thousand issues I use a jira-python script and delete them one at time. Takes a while but it's reliable